# regex with XE currency

Tags: regex, vb.net

guys I'm trying to make my personal app with VB.Net

and all of my code is working fine except one thing, which is the regex

I want to get this value

[The Highlighted Value that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FEZR.png)

From this [URL](https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert.cgi?template=pca-new&Amount=15&From=USD&To=SAR&image.x=39&image.y=9)

I tried this regex:

```
("([0-9]+.+[1-9]+ (SAR)+)")
```

and it's not working very well (only works with some currency but not all).

so guys can you help with the perfect regex ?

***Update:
here is the whole function code:

```
Private Sub doCalculate()
    ' Need the scraping
    Dim Str As System.IO.Stream
    Dim srRead As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim strAmount As String
    strAmount = currencyAmount.Text

    ' Get values from the textboxes
    Dim strFrom() As String = Split(currecnyFrom.Text, " - ")
    Dim strTo() As String = Split(currecnyTo.Text, " - ")

    ' Web fetching variables
    Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert.cgi?template=pca-new&Amount=" + strAmount + "&From=" + strFrom(1) + "&To=" + strTo(1) + "&image.x=39&image.y=9")
    Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse

    Str = resp.GetResponseStream
    srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)


    ' Match the response
    Try
        Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
        Dim myRegExp As New Regex("(\d+\.\d+ SAR)")

        myMatches = myRegExp.Matches(srRead.ReadToEnd)

        ' Search for all the words in the string
        Dim sucessfulMatch As Match
        For Each sucessfulMatch In myMatches
            mainText.Text = sucessfulMatch.Value
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        mainText.Text = "Unable to connect to XE"
    Finally
        ' Close the streams
        srRead.close()
        Str.Close()
    End Try
    convertToLabel.Text = strAmount + " " + strFrom(0) + " Converts To: "
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by it's working with some currencies but not all? I'd suggest update your post with sample dataset along with what it matches and what not.

Comment: @Saleem: Check comments in the answer posted below.

Comment: Check the documentation for [global matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx). I guess if you avoid `For Each` loop and simple put `mainText.Text = sucessfulMatch.Value
` You will get the first match. Try it.

Comment: Replace `myMatches = myRegExp.Matches(srRead.ReadToEnd)

        ' Search for all the words in the string
        Dim sucessfulMatch As Match
        For Each sucessfulMatch In myMatches
            mainText.Text = sucessfulMatch.Value
        Next` with `Dim myMatch As Match = myRegExp.Match(srRead.ReadToEnd) //
            mainText.Text = myMatch.Value`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much sir, the problem has been solved. Can you please re post your comment as an answer so I can give you the feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the currency value that appears first. Thus, you need to replace

```
myMatches = myRegExp.Matches(srRead.ReadToEnd)
' Search for all the words in the string
Dim sucessfulMatch As Match
For Each sucessfulMatch In myMatches
    mainText.Text = sucessfulMatch.Value
Next
```

with the following lines:

```
Dim myMatch As Match = myRegExp.Match(srRead.ReadToEnd)
mainText.Text = myMatch.Value
```

I also recommend using the [following regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%2BSAR%5Cb&i=15%20USD%20%3D%2056.256788%20SAR%0D%0A%0D%0AUnited%20States%20Dollars%0D%0A1%20USD%20%3D%203.75006):

```
\b\d+\.\d+\p{Zs}+SAR\b
```

Explanation:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\.` -  a literal dot
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\p{Zs}+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespace
- `SAR\b` - whole word `SAR`.

Comment: Just FYI: to actually match any horizontal whitespace in .NET regex, `\p{Zs}` is not enough, use `[\p{Zs}\t]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this regex.

**Regex:** `(\d+\.\d+ SAR)`

**Explanation:**

- `\d+` looks for multiple digits.
- `\.\d+` looks for decimal digits.
- `SAR` matches literal string `SAR` which is your currency unit.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS3aM8/2)**

---

> I tried this regex:
>
> ("([0-9]+.+[1-9]+ (SAR)+)") and it's not working very well (only works
>   with some currency but not all).

What you are doing here is matching `multiple digits` `anything` `multiple digits` `SAR multiple times.`

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to capture the whole number (if capturing anything at all)?

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but suddenly I got the wrong value not the that I highlighted, so how can I get that one plz?

Comment: @SebastianProske: You were right. Updated my answer.

Comment: The problem is there is two word (SAR) in the webpage so how can I choose between them with the regex?

Comment: still not working my friend I've ended up with the other value that I don't want to

Comment: @rooot_999: Actually there are three. Could you explain how are you capturing values ? Because there are conversion values too. And this regex will catch those too.

Comment: Yup three :( and always ended up with this one (3.75044 SAR )

Comment: @rooot_999: Could you post your code for regex ? If you could search globally then you will be able to capture both values.

Comment: @rooot_999: I have seen the URL, but what code are you using for regex. Please post it in your question, not in comments.

Comment: @noob here you go sir I've uploaded the whole function for regex so you can understand it well http://textuploader.com/5nfqa

Comment: @rooot_999, Please post your code in your original post. Anything in comments will loose formatting.

Comment: @Saleem sorry I didn't know how to do it, I've added it now. Thanks